# Filter from table for column having comma and pipe separated values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have one table names TblDiscount, in which one column(product) has a comma and pipe sepearated value like

```
"Product1|1,Product2|1,Product3|1",
"Product2|1,Product4|1,Product5|2",
```

etc. 
So records are stores as below:

```
Id      |       Product
1       |  Product1|1,Product2|1,Product3|1
2       |  Product2|1,Product4|1,Product5|2
3       |  Product6|1,Product7|1,Product8|2
```

I want to apply the filter on this column(product).
So, if I search for "product5" then it should return the second row with Id=2.
When I use In-memory List, it works  fine

```
  List<string> products = new List<string> { "22235|1,22232|1,22246|1", 
    "22246|1,22245|1,22247|1" };
    var result = products.Where(x => x.Split(',').Any(c => c.Split('|').Any(y 
    => y.Equals("22247")))).FirstOrDefault();
```

but when I run it with sql database table it gives me error: Actual code is as below:

```
var isExist = this.DataContext.ProductTbl.Where(x => x.IsActive && 
x.product.Split(',').Any(c => c.Split('|').Any(y => y.Contains(productCode)))).Any()
```

it give me error as:
"
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.String'. Actual 'System.String[]'.
"
Please Help!!!

Comment: Did you consider normalizing your data?

Comment: I can not do it as it is existing structure and it has lot of dependency

Comment: Please post real not working code.

Comment: I have added the actual code which I am trying.

Comment: @Raj that's a terrible way to store data. You can cover it up for this single query but it will bite you again when you try to make *another* query, eg try to find a specific product or count the number of products. You'll have to fix this sooner or later.

Comment: @Raj in any case, forget about *LINQ*. You need to parse this string, not query it. The parsing code, even what you wrote now, *can't* be used in LINQ-to-Entities because quite simply, it can't be translated to SQL. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it's a query language that will be translated to SQL eventually.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Yes it is terrible way, but this is running on production and I cannot change it right now. So I have to find a workaround for now. Later on it has to be redesign.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a List<string> to string[]?  Try ToArray().

Comment: @Raj as for what you are trying to do, search for rows that match a specific product, well, that's exactly what you *can't* do due to the bad design. The only thing you can do in SQL is a `WHERE Product LIKE '%' +productCode +'|%'`. Performance will be awful because such a `LIKE` clause can't take advantage of any indexes.

Comment: @Raj it's not running, or you wouldn't be asking this question. You *can't* search for a specific product. You have to use a wildcard search with no indexes. I suspect that's what the production code already does. If you though you could fix that with LINQ, you can't.

Comment: @jdweng ToArray() is not working

Comment: @Raj the only way to search for a productcode in SQL is with `WHERE Product LIKE '%' +@productCode +'|%'`. To do the same in LINQ-to-Entities you need to use [DbFunctions.Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.like?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) in EF 6.2 or EF.Functions.Like in EF Core 2.0 , eg `ProductTbl.Where(prd=>DbFunctions.Like(prd.Product,"%" +productCode +"|%"))`

Comment: @Raj once you load the matching rows you can use a simple C# function to parse the `product` column. A regex would be the fastest way to find the ID that appears after a product code, eg `product5|(?<id>\d+)` will return the ID value in the `id` named group

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I did the same way by loading only matching rows and then applied the split function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out entities using LINQ you would have to convert `ProductTbl` to eg. list. Try:

```
var isExist = this.DataContext.ProductTbl.ToList().Where(x => x.IsActive && 
x.product.Split(',').Any(c => c.Split('|').Any(y => y.Contains(productCode)))).Any();
```

However if you need to only get rows that have some product you can try:

```
var isExist = this.DataContext.ProductTbl.Any(x=> x.IsActive  && ("," + x.product).Contains(productCode + "|"));
```

Comment: Loading an entire table in memory is rather inefficient. Besides, check what the query tries to do. If tries to find a *specific* product. The only way to do so in SQL would be to use `LIKE`.

Comment: It gives the expected result but the drawback is it loads entire table data in memory

Comment: @Raj if you don't want to load everything, you'll have to think up of a *SQL* query that does what you want. The only thing that does that is `LIKE`. There's no `Split` function in SQL, so what you tried can't be translated to SQL

Comment: The second line can't be translated to SQL

Comment: It is work around. but for now it has serve my purpose.